# WCF Publish / Subscribe: How to handle client side timeout so as not to miss information?

Tags: wcf, timeout, publish-subscribe, reconnect

I have a simple WCF publish/subscribe up and running, [based on this example](http://www.arquitecturadesoftware.org/blogs/hugoribeiro/archive/2008/01/28/publisher-subscriber-implementation-with-wcf.aspx). I am using netTcpBinding with reliableSession enabled. Everything works fine with the functionality (the subscribed clients receive the published data as expected), but at some point the connection times out if it has been idle for a while. I can set up the publisher to reconnect on timeout, but the subscribed clients will be lost. Is there a way to get them back? I would prefer not to just increase the timeouts, as that could cause other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually came up with was to assign a unique identifier to every message that was published, and cache the published message in the service adapter (in the same place where I was storing the callbacks to the subscribed clients. Whenever I published the message, subscribers would receive the message **and** the corresponding unique id. Subscribers could then use the channel.Faulted event to reconnect and resubscribe to the service with a special method that takes the last received message id as a parameter.

Service code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Operation used by the subscriber to subscribe to events published.
    /// </summary>
    public void Resubscribe(int lastReceivedMessageId)
    {
        // Get callback contract
        IPubSubCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPubSubCallback>();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
        {
            adapter.Resubscribe(lastReceivedMessageId, callback);
        }); 
    }
```

Adapter code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Operation used by the subscriber to resubscribe to events published.
    /// </summary>
    public void Resubscribe(int lastReceivedMessageId, IPubSubCallback callback)
    {
        try
        {
            // Send the subscriber any missed messages
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> missedMessage in publishedMessages.Where(x => x.Key > lastReceivedMessageId))
            {
                callback.MessagePublished(missedMessage.Value, missedMessage.Key);
            }

            // Add the subscriber callback to the list of active subscribers
            if (!callbacks.Contains(callback))
            {
                callbacks.Add(callback);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore subscription, callbacks failed again
        }
    }
```

The service can then work out what the client has missed, and resend those messages in the correct order.

This solution seems to be working well for me, but I have a feeling that there must be a better way to do this. Comments / additional answers are very welcome! :)

Comment: If the "clients" aren't end-user machines but a limited number of servers, you could try [MSMQ based Pub/Sub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx) with WCF. It's "better" in the sense that the messages are guaranteed to be delivered and this occurs asynchronously. The down side is that configuring MSMQ on each machine is only feasible if the set up & config is automated.

Comment: Thanks! That approach might be useful for some of my future publish-subscribe needs. I will take a look into how to set this up :)